# display and Updating data from form's instances in one other static form in csharp

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am working on a queue management project in csharp. I've already added the elements and called them from the queue and so far so good. However, the problem is that I can't find a way to display the data on a static screen/form as is often done in banks, hospitals, etc...
Does anyone have an idea on how to code to be able to display the workstations and update the called elements in real time? Thanks in advance. I hope you understood me.

```
 speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
 speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync("Ticket numéro " + lblNumApl.Text + "," + lblSessionpostetravail.Text);
```

In any case, I have already tried to display the data to my display form in the following way:

In my call button at the level of the workstation form "Workstation" I put the code which retrieves the number called and the name of the workstation, I assign them in static public variables which are in a static class finally to transmit its data to my "FrmDisplay" form but when I execute, the display form is not static! It is instantiated according to the number of workstations that make calls:

```
                            {
                                LesClasses.ActualiserAfficheur.vlrGht1 = lblNumApl.Text;
                            }
                            if (lblSessionpostetravail.Text == LesClasses.ActualiserAfficheur.nomGht2)
                            {
                                LesClasses.ActualiserAfficheur.vlrGht2 = lblNumApl.Text;
                            }
                            if (lblSessionpostetravail.Text == LesClasses.ActualiserAfficheur.nomGht3)
                            {
                                LesClasses.ActualiserAfficheur.vlrGht3 = lblNumApl.Text;
                            }
                            if (lblSessionpostetravail.Text == LesClasses.ActualiserAfficheur.nomGht4)
                            {
                                LesClasses.ActualiserAfficheur.vlrGht4 = lblNumApl.Text;
                            }
                            if (lblSessionpostetravail.Text == LesClasses.ActualiserAfficheur.nomGht5)
                            {
                                LesClasses.ActualiserAfficheur.vlrGht5 = lblNumApl.Text;
                            }
```